# Reducing Second order PDE System to First-Order

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I am confused as to how to choose the variables for $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ when reducing the second-order PDE systems to first-order. This is the question I am referring to for help:

[image]

Comment: You just need one additional function $w := \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ to obtain a system of first-order PDEs for $(u,v,w)$.